# the increase of size by javascript uriencode

Tags: javascript, php, encode

I have a text in Chinese of 1586 chars long and Javascript encodeURIComponent end up with 10522 characters long that can not be sent as a parameter in URL line for PHP to process ? (PHP error message URI too long)

The first question is why encode increase almost 7 times in string length? and the second question is how to get around.

Comment: Post or Zip it..........

Comment: Sending that large chunks of data in the URL is rarely advisable. Use POST instead. I can't answer to why it gets 7 times bigger, but if it is in Chinese, I guess it will need a few extra bytes per character when it gets urlencoded.

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Chinese characters are made up of more bytes, you can check the make up of individual characters here: https://mothereff.in/byte-counter so that's where you get a 3 times increase.

Additionally, URI encoding expands characters with special meaning into more characters with a safer meaning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Put both of these together and a 7 increase in what you're seeing makes sense.

As for how to get around it, it really depends on the server, i.e. if it's a configurable property you could increase it. But as others have suggested in comments if you're hitting URI too long errors, your approach is probably wrong.